# SBIC instruction in AVR Assembler

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm starting to learn Assembler and I have this doubt. I have the following segment of code

```
LDI R16, 0
OUT DDRB, R16 ; Configures port B as an input port
SBIC PORTB, 0
LDI R18, 0xAA
OUT PORTC, R18
RETI
```

I've read that what `SBIC` does is checking (in this case) if the bit 0 of port B is clear. If it is, then it skips the next instruction.

My questions are:

**1)** Does `OUT DDRB, R16` write 0's in all of the bits of port B or is it just a configuration instruction but it doesn't *write* anything? In other words: are the bits of port B all set to 0?

**2)** If they are all set to 0, then the instruction after the `SBIC` will be skipped. But is only the first instruction that comes next that is skipped, or everything until `RETI` is reached?

Comment: As the comment says, it configures the port as input. It doesn't write anything. `SBIC` will return whatever the external circuitry connected to the port pins supplies, and it only checks a single bit and it also only skips a single instruction. This is all written in the manual.

Comment: Isn't it possible to write 1's and 0's in the pins of a port with something like `LDI R16, 0xFF` and then `OUT PORTA, R16`? In this case what `SBIC` returns wouldn't depend on the external circuitry, or am I wrong? And one last thing: is it possible to know whether `SBIC` will skip the next instruction with just that segment of code I wrote in the question?

Comment: If the port is configured as input, writing to it usually controls the internal pull-up (but consult your particular chip documentation to make sure). No, you can't tell whether `SBIC` will skip or not. If you could there wouldn't be any point using it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first instruction writes 0's in all bits of the DDRB register. I assume from the comment and the name of the register this makes all the pins of port B inputs. This wouldn't explicitly output anything, but depending on how the device configured electrically, any external device trying to read any of the port B pins at that point might see a change in value since they're no longer configured for reading.

The next instruction tests the 0th bit of PORTB register, the value of which will depend on whatever is connected the corresponding pin.  If it's clear the next instruction `LDI R18, 0xAA` is skipped. If it's set the next instruction is executed.

This means that the value stored in the PORTC register by `OUT PORTC, R18` depends on both the state of the first pin of port B and the value contained in R18 at the start of the execution of your example code.